# Spectrogram between indices matlab

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I have a signal that is 507150 samples long and I want a spectrogram between samples 202336 and 234398 only. How should I format the spectrogram function? Or is there another method?

Comment: What's wrong with passing only the desired samples to `spectrogram`, _i.e_: `spectorgram(signal(202336:234398))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is as simple as this:

Assume `x` is your sample.

```
S=spectrogram(x(202336:234398))
```